unable to record flow because of proxy
I have to record mobile application using jmeter. For this, I have did all the required configuration on iphone and in jmeter.
Also api's are getting recorded in jmeter. but there is one flow of sign in option. Once user did sign in , then button should changed to sign out state.
During the recording with the proxy setting (manual) button is not changing to sign out but when we  changed the proxy of mobile to normal , then sign in button changed to sign out.
Can you give me solution how to do this? how to record complete script?

Take a look at jmeter.log file, normally it should contain the reason for the behaviour. If it doesn't - increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level.
I can assume that your sign in/sign out uses the domain which differs from the domain where API requests are going so you might to play with JMeter SSL configuration and add another domain for that.
In any case in order to be able to record HTTPS traffic you need to import JMeter's certificate onto your device and enable full trust for this.

Yes , I imported jmeter certification on device as well as enabled it to trusted(enabled the toggle on).
